# how to distribute text data on database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, save

I've question about data distribution.

I've large text for example text has billion paragraphs and they are growing every day

I want separate each paragraph and  save them in different rows

Paragraphs are divided by types. every paragraph has some of type for example I have 10 000 types.

**I've two BAD ideas**

1. save all data in 1 table. - *program will working slow*
2. create 10 000 tables for each. - *I just know that it's bad idea*

my question is how to separate data, how to distribute it in database?

Comment: One table would normally be the way to go.  However, your data organization should be based on how you want to use the data.  Also, "billions of paragraphs" suggests "hundreds of Gbytes".  I might suggest a database other than SQLite.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, 
Users will select data using type. for example SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE = "TYPE".
what you think will it slow with one table?

Comment: What is the format of data in your text file? Is it csv?

Comment: It will just nvarchar in database. one paragraph one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's nothing wrong with putting all of the data in one table.**

If your data structure and usage imply that the data should all be in one table (and from what you've told us, I think they do), then you should put them in one table.  There's nothing wrong with having billions of rows in a table.  Robust ODBMs can handle this. (Though, as Gordon Linoff comments, you should consider something more sophisticated than SQLite).

**Indexes are the way to efficiently extract a subset of the data.**

You mentioned that you will retrieve data with queries like this:

```
select * from table where type = 'type';
```

If you put an index on the type field, it will enable you to efficiently extract those rows without searching through all billion records.  The basic syntax for creating an index on a column is like so:

```
create index index_name on table_name (column_name);
```

Though there are various options, depending on your ODBMS, that may be relevant to increasing performance.